# Prevent AndroidStudio/Gradle from building a project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

**Short version**

Can I stop AndroidStudio/Gradle from building a project that is a dependency of another project? (it's an NDK project, and I am happt to build it manually).

**Long Version**

I am trying to convert an Eclipse workspace to an AS project. There are several projects in the Eclipse workspace. Two of them are NDK projects.

AS does not yet have production-quality NDK support (and this is a production app). I would like to be able to still import these projects so that I can see them and in the expectation that one day AS will support NDK.

In the mean time I would like to stop gradle from trying to build them (I can happily manually use NDK build).

Can this be done?

Edit: There seem to be a number of related responses that suggest right-clicking on the module and going to the 'Gradle' sub-menu to disable build...but I can see no gradle sub-menu in the latest AS.